# java regex match string containing words with no digits and optionally separated by comma

Tags: java, regex

Inspired by a previous question, I'm trying to find a regex that matches a string containing at least one word formed by only characters, not digits. So \w is not applicable. Comma separated words are ok only if there are not two commas in a row.

This is the best I've found is:

```
(.*\s+,?)*([a-zA-Z]+)+(,?\s+.*)*
```

but it doesn't match the following strings:

```
aaaaa,11111
11111,aaaaa
11111,aaaaa,
,aaaaa
aaaaa,
,aaaaa,
aaaaa,11111,,
,,aaaaa,bbbbb
aaaaa,,bbbbb,ccccc
aaaaa,bbbbb,,ccccc
aaaaa,bbbbb,ccccc
aaaaa,11111
```

Here's a test program to determine if a regex is correct:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

class Ideone
{
public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
{
    String regex = "(.*\\s+,?)*([a-zA-Z]+)+(,?\\s+.*)*";
    String shouldMatch[] = new String[] {
        "aaaaa",
        "aaaaa bbbbb",
        "aaaaa 11111",
        "11111 aaaaa",
        "aaaaa,11111",
        "aaaaa, 11111",
        "aaaaa,  11111",
        "11111,aaaaa",
        "11111, aaaaa",
        "11111,  aaaaa",
        "11111,aaaaa,",
        ",aaaaa",
        "aaaaa,",
        ",aaaaa,",
        "aaaaa,11111,,",
        ",,aaaaa,bbbbb",
        "aaaaa1111 bbbbb",
        "aaaaa1111 bbbbb ccccc",
        "aaaaa1111bbbbb ccccc",
        "aaaaa11111bbbbb ccccc 22222",
        ",,aaaaa bbbbb",
        "aaaaa,,bbbbb ccccc",
        "aaaaa,,bbbbb,ccccc",
        "aaaaa,bbbbb,,ccccc",
        "aaaaa,bbbbb,ccccc",
        "aaaaa,11111"
    };

    String shouldNotMatch[] = new String[] {
        "aaaaa11111",
        "11111bbbbb",
        "aaaaa11111bbbbb",
        "aaaaa11111bbbbb 11111ccccc",
        "aaaaa11111bbbbb ccccc11111",
        "aaaaa,,bbbbb",
        "aaaaa,,11111",
        ",,aaaaa",
        "aaaaa,,",
        "11111",
        "11111,22222",
        "11111 22222",
        ""
    };

    boolean result = true;

    for(String stringToTest : shouldMatch){
        if (!(stringToTest.matches(regex))){
            System.out.println(stringToTest + " Don't match. WRONG.");
            result = false;
        }
    }

    for(String stringToTest : shouldNotMatch){
        if (stringToTest.matches(regex)){
            System.out.println(stringToTest + " Match. WRONG.");
            result = false;
        }
    }

    if (result){
        System.out.println("Congratulation, your regex is right.");
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("Result of one ore more test is wrong.");
    }
}
}
```

Edit: Added some more String that should not match the regex, empty string and numbers only (plus comma or spaces).

Comment: You say that csw are okay if commas are not in a row, but have several examples like: `",,aaaaa bbbbb"`, which are supposed to match?

Comment: @SteveP. ,,aaaa,bbbb should match because bbbb is preceded by one comma only

Comment: `"aaaaa,,bbbbb ccccc"` is in match, too.

Comment: @SteveP. OP is testing the *existence* of a matching word.

Comment: @SteveP. yes, maybe I was not clear. It should match if there is at least one word formed by characters and optionally followed or preceded by one comma. So, aaaaa,,bbbbb cccc should match because ccccc is right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works, I checked with your test program:

```
String regex = "^.*?(?<=\\s|^|,)(?<!,,)[A-Za-z]+(?!,,)(?=\\s|,|$).*$";
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

`^` "begins with"
`.*?` non-greedy for any non-newline character
`(?<=\\s|^|,)` Positive look behind for white space or beginning of string or `,`, since they are the only valid characters that can come before our definition of word
`(?<!,,)` Negative look behind for `,,`, as they are now allowed before word
`[A-Za-z]+` 1 or more letters
`(?!,,)` Negative look ahead for `,,` as they are now allowed after word
`(?=\\s|,|$)` Positive look ahead for white space or end of string or `,`, since they are the only valid characters that can come after our definition of word
`$` "ends with"

Comment: @holap That was surprisingly pretty complicated.  It looked so simple to begin with.  Good job with the writing the test program, that made it much easier to figure out what you want/what worked.

Comment: I put it in Debuggex.com (select Python).. It gave a nice graphic. Try it. You can even click the "Embed in StackOverflow", grab the code and add it here!

Comment: You rock dude! Yes, the question seemed very simple to me too at first, but I realized it's not at all. This regex will teach me a lot of things I suppose. Thank you very much. I'll study it, maybe I'll need to ask some farther explanation.

Comment: @holap No problem.  I added a graphic, which may help.  Good luck!  That was a fun problem!

Answer (score 1):

Based on your example following should work:

```
String regex = "(?i)(?=.*?(?<!,,)\\b[a-z]+\\b(?!,,))[, \\w]+";
```

Comment: You managed to create this visual within 5 minutes of the question. That's impressive! What did you use?

Comment: @ChthonicProject: Created that on debuggex.com

Comment: @anubhava Run it through his test program, quite a few, I don't recall.

Comment: @anubhava impressive your reply. It doesn't working on "11111,  aaaaa" for istance, or "aaaaa,,bbbbb", but many other too.

Comment: @SteveP. Yes I was looking at that. And not I'm confused `,,aaaaa,bbbbb` should match but `aaaaa,,11111` shouldn't.

Comment: @anubhava yes, beacuse aaaaa,,11111 is formed by aaaaa followed by two comma in a row. So aaaaa is not good. But in ,,aaaaa,bbbbb the bbbbb is preceded by only one comma, so it's ok. Hope is more clear.

Comment: @holap: Ok I think I understand it better now. Let me rework my answer.

Comment: @holap: Answer updated but **another doubt**: Why `aaaaa,,bbbbb` should be NO MATCH but `,,aaaaa,bbbbb` should be a MATCH?

Comment: @anubhava Because `,bbbbb` is acceptable, as it's only preceded by one comma.  My answer is correct.  Perhaps you can make it better, I couldn't at least not at this point...

Comment: @anubhava because in "aaaaa,,bbbbb" aaaaa is followeb by two commas, and bbbb is preceded by two commas. So neigher aaaa nor bbbb are eligible. In ",,aaaaa,bbbbb" aaaaa is not right because is precedeb by ",," but bbbb is preceded by only one comma, so it's ok.

Comment: @SteveP. yes, just commented. Thank you so much, to both of you.

Comment: You're still missing the `,,` cases.  `\\b` will cause that, I tried it, too.

Comment: Sorry got distracted in some work and couldn't complete this in time. I have edited my code which I believe passes all the tests listed in your question.

Comment: @anubhava No problem, thank you anyway. Actually your regex passed all original tests, but it's wrong. I missed to test the case of a string with numbers only. Your regex would not pass that. But your solution was inspiring. Upvoted your answer.